# Create a font resource from byte array on Win32

Tags: winapi

I have a byte array that contains the contents of a read in font file. I'd like WinAPI (No Gdi+) to create a font resource from it, so I could use it for rendering text.

I only know about [AddFontResourceExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourceexw), that loads in a font resource from file, and [AddFontMemResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontmemresourceex), which sounded like what I'd need, but it seems to me that it's still some resource-system thing and the data would have to be pre-associated with the program.

Can I somehow convert my loaded in byte-array into a font resource? (Possibly without writing it to a file and then calling `AddFontResourceExW`)

Comment: Save to a temp file and add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a font from a resource script into memory, you use code like the following (you didn't add a language tag, so I'm using C/C++ code - let me know if that's a problem):

```cpp
    HANDLE H_myfont = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HINSTANCE hResInstance = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    HRSRC ares = FindResource(hResInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDF_MYID), L"BINARY");
    if (ares) {
        HGLOBAL amem = LoadResource(hResInstance, ares);
        if (amem != nullptr) {
            void *adata = LockResource(amem);
            DWORD nFonts = 0, len = SizeofResource(hResInstance, ares);
            H_myfont = AddFontMemResourceEx(adata, len, nullptr, &nFonts);
        }
    }
```

The key line here is `void *adata = LockResource(amem);` - this converts the font resource loaded as an `HGLOBAL` into 'accessible memory' ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-lockresource)). Now, assuming your byte array is in the correct format (see below), you could probably just pass a pointer to it (as `void*`) in the call to `AddFontMemResourceEx`. (You can use your known array size in place of calling `SizeofResource`.)

I would suggest code something like this:

```cpp
    void *my_font_data = (void*)(font_byte_array); // Your byte array data
    DWORD nFonts = 0, len = sizeof(font_byte_array);
    H_myfont = AddFontMemResourceEx(my_font_data, len, nullptr, &nFonts);
```

which (hopefully) will give you a loaded and useable font resource.

When you're done with the font (which, once loaded, can be used just like any system-installed font), you can release it with:

```cpp
    RemoveFontMemResourceEx(H_myfont);
```

As I don't have your byte array, I can't (obviously) test this idea. However, if you do try it, please let us know if it works. (If it doesn't, there may be some other, relatively straightforward, steps that need to be added.)

NOTE: Although I can't say 100% what the *exact* format expected of a "font resource" is, the fact that code given above works (for me) with a resource defined in the .rc script as a `BINARY` with a normal, ".ttf" file, suggests that, if your byte array follows the format of a Windows Font File, then it should work. This is how I have included a font as an embedded resource:

```
IDF_MYFONT  BINARY  L"..\\Resource\\MyFont.ttf"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! One more question, because I've never used this part of the WinAPI: Is there a way to extract all the font faces (or face names) from a loaded font resource? When I create a font with `CreateFontW`, I might not know the face name, so a default would be nice (from the file, not from the system).

Comment: @PeterLenkefi I'll need to think about that - and I shall! (Meantime, let's clean up all the previous comments.)